# How to adjust the size of text and otherwise format the text rendered in a popover in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, format, hover, popover

In running the below code, when hovering the cursor over one of the images rendered in the "Col_help" column on the right of the table, a message pops up to assist the user. How do I increase the font size of that popover text and the size of that popover box too? I would also like to also edit the text so that it is easier for the reader, such as inserting line breaks, using bullet list, etc. Is this possible too?

The reason I am doing this is to provide the user with "helps" in this manner.

Code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

DF = data.frame(
  Col_1 = c("This is row 1","This is row 2"), 
  Col_Help = c(
    as.character(img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/python-logo.png", title = "My first help text", style = "width: 50px;")),
    as.character(img(src = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png", title = "My second help text", style = "width: 50px;"))
  ),
  text = c("Row 1 does xxx","Row 2 does yyy"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(br(),rHandsontableOutput('my_table'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable::rhandsontable(
      DF,
      allowedTags = "<em><b><strong><a><big><img>"
    ) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = c(200, 80)) %>%
      hot_col(1:2, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer")) %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = ifelse(names(DF) != "text", 100, 0.1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```